# Translations into TFL (truth functional logic)

Tags: logic, translation

I've been struggling with truth functional logic translations (very new to this) and I was wondering if someone can help me with strategy at getting better with this stuff. I feel super all over the place and fail to do even the simplest ones. Any direction or maybe tips would be greatly appreciated.

My failed attempt#1

Question:
Provided Ben does not feel sick, he will drive only if Amy does not drive or Cory pays

My Answer(incorrect):
(-Y&(-DorQ))>E

My failed attempt#2

Question:
Unless Cory and Amy do, Ben will not ride the Ferris wheel; but if he does ride the Ferris wheel, then if he drinks lots of soda he'll feel sick

My Answer(incorrect, i didn't get very far I got lost at "; but"):
(R&T)>B

Comment: ["P only if Q" is "if P, then Q"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/are-if-p-then-q-and-q-only-if-p-equivalent) i.e. **P → Q**.

Comment: Thus, working step-by-step "he [Ben] will drive only if Amy does not drive or Cory pays" will be: **B → (¬D ∨ C)**

Comment: Then we add the part "Provided Ben does not feel sick" that is **¬S → ...**

Comment: And see [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31032/how-does-unless-mean-or-intuitively) for "unless".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! :) :) :)